# Parameterizing pytest function with different tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have a scenario where there are 1000's of test cases in excel.
Is there a way to parameterize the test so that all the test cases run?

I have used `pandas` and I am getting all the test cases while iterating through:

```
def getCases():
    excel_file = 'path of excel'
    result = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    count_row = result.shape[0]
    for i in range(count_row):
        r = result.iloc[i]
        return [r]
```

Each row in the excel table is a test case and the result returned is in the form of dictionary, which I want to pass as input to my test case.

I use the following fixture to pass these parameters to my test functions:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=PWC.getCases())
def getData(self, request):
    return request.param
```

The problem is that after the first iteration, it is not reaching this code 
and my test case does not return to the `getCases()` function.
How do I customize the **params**  in **pytest fixture** so that I will be able to run all the cases?
Will I be able to pass a range inside `getCases` as parameter?

Comment: You have to use `yield` instead of `return`. Also, I'm not sure why you are making an array of the result - is this needed?

Comment: each row is a test case and the result returned is in the form of dictionary, i have to pass that dictionary as input to my test case. i wanted to wrap this dictionary into a list and send.

Comment: Ok, I'll put out that in an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to return the control to the function you have to use `yield` instead of `return`. Assuming each row contains both the input and the result data for the test, this would look something like this:

```
def getCases():
    excel_file = 'path of excel'
    result = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    count_row = result.shape[0]
    for i in range(count_row):
        yield result.iloc[i]

@pytest.fixture(params=getCases())
def data(self, request):
    return request.param

def test_data(data):
    assert my_fct(data['input']) == data['result']
```

(assuming that there is only one input parameter in your tested function)

Comment: I tried the above since I have a similar situation wherein each row in the csv table is a test case. It works fine, however the result is not written out for each step. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Do you mean just verbose output like `pytest -vv`, or something else?

Comment: yes, I forgot the -vv flag. It did the trick. Thank you :)